# 'then' block is getting executed before called function which returns promise

Tags: javascript, promise, protractor, ui-automation

I am new to protractor and javascript. I am building a test framework where each test suit has corresponding module file and locator file. In test cases of test suit file , test modules are being called by passing parameter. When i tried to nest the called function from module in 'then' block ; then blocks starts execution before called function completes. Refer the following code files :

```
 UserPage.js // Test suit from where modules are called

var d = require("../Data/TestCaseData.js");
var login = require("../Modules/LoginPageModule.js");
var user = require("../Modules/UserPageModule.js");
var userl = require("../Locators/UserPageLocators");

describe('first test suit',function(){

    beforeEach(function(){

           browser.get(d.iManUrl).then(function(){
            browser.manage().window().maximize();
            login.OSPLogin(d.username,d.password);
        })
    });

    it ('Creating user',function(){
        var person = {'Username' : 'u6' , 'Context' : 'novell' , 'Last name' : 'last' , 'Password' : 'n'};

        user.InputData(person).then(function(){
        element(by.buttonText("Create")).click().then(function(){
            browser.sleep(5000);
        });
    })

    })


})
```

Below is module :

```
var usercreated = false;

function UserPageModule(){

    this.InputData = function(person){

        return this.InputUserPasswordContext(person).then(function(person){

            this.fill =function(data){
                for (var key in data) {
                      console.log(key);
                      element(by.xpath(user.identificationAddValueButtonXpath.replace("Input Field", key))).click();
                      element(by.css(user.identificationValueInputCss)).sendKeys(person [ key ]);
                      element(by.buttonText(user.identificationAcceptValueButtonText)).click();               
                    }
            }
            return new Promise(function(resolve,request){
                 return resolve(this.fill(person));
            })
        });
    }

    /*this.InputData = function(person){
        this.InputUserPasswordContext(person).then(function(person){
            this.InputFields(person);
        });
    }*/


    this.InputUserPasswordContext = function(person){
            return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
                //Navigating to user page
                element(by.css(landing.userLinkCss)).click();

                //Clicking on add button
                element(by.css(user.createuserButtonCss)).click();

                //Inputting Username
                element(by.css(user.usernameInputCss)).sendKeys(person.Username).then(function(){
                    delete person.Username;
                });

                //Input password
                element(by.css(user.identificationPasswordInputCss)).sendKeys(person.Password);
                element(by.css(user.identificationRetypeInputCss)).sendKeys(person.Password).then(function(){
                    delete person.Password;
                });

                //Inputting context
                element(by.css(user.contextInputCss)).sendKeys(person.Context).then(function(){
                    delete person.Context;
                }).then(function(){
                    resolve(person);
                })
            })                  
    }




}

module.exports = new UserPageModule
```

**All the steps run sequentially till 'for loop'. But then blocks executes before for loop.I am not getting any error also.**

Answer (score 0):

For Javascript, each `Function` has an implicit `this`.  When you using nested function, it's easy to make mistake on using `this`.

```
function UserPageModule(){

    this.InputData = function(person){

        return this.InputUserPasswordContext(person).then(function abc(person){


          for (let key in data) {
              console.log(key);
              element(by.xpath(user.identificationAddValueButtonXpath.replace("Input Field", key))).click();
              element(by.css(user.identificationValueInputCss)).sendKeys(person [ key ]);
              element(by.buttonText(user.identificationAcceptValueButtonText)).click();               
          }


        }).catch(function(err){
           console.log('err: ' + err);
        });
    }

    this.InputUserPasswordContext = function(person){
      ...
    }

}
```

Comment: This solution did not work. Observations : 1 - Anything which is returned by "return resolve();" of  function 'xyz' is executed after then block of " user.InputData(person).then(function(value){
   element(by.buttonText("Create")).click();
  }) " which is section of test case block in question

Comment: Additional info : In beforeEach section 'login.OSPLogin(d.username,d.password);' doesn't return promise. But i guess, that should not be issue.

Comment: Try change `for (var key in data) {`  to  `for (let key in data) {`

Comment: I tried changing but same behavior. Even if i am returning simple statement or variable instead of 'xyz' method; 'then' block is getting executed first.

Comment: I remove the `return new Promise()` and add a `catch` in case some error occur in InputUserPasswordContext(). Please try again.